# paintEvent() in PyQt called unnecessarily

Tags: qt4, pyqt4

I'm using PyQt4 and I want to draw a line based on user's click on an existing image which is displayed as an imagelabel. The image shows properly and after a clicking an icon in toolbar, the user will draw a line on the image.

I've overridden the `mousePressEvent()` and `mouseReleaseEvent()` to get the x, y positions. I've defined `paintEvent()` to draw the line.

```
def mousePressEvent(self,event):
    self.startx=event.x()
    self.starty=event.y()

def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event):
    self.endx=event.x()
    self.endy=event.y()

def paintEvent(self,event):
    painter=QPainter()
    painter.begin(self)
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.darkGray,3))
    painter.drawLine(self.startx,self.starty,self.endx,self.endy)
    painter.end()
```

#### Problem:

1. Since I used `self` for mouseevents, the error says:
   **object has no attribute 'self.startx'** — (How should I associate a widget to mouseevents in PyQt?)
2. `paintEvent()`  gets called even when i move the mouse around the app.

Thanks in advance…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend making the line a seperate object that gets created once you release the mouse.  To do so create a new class:

```
class line(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, point1, point2):
        self.p1 = point1
        self.p2 = point2

    def paintEvent(self,event):
        painter=QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.darkGray,3))
        painter.drawLine(self.p1,self.p2)
        painter.end()
```

Then I would define your mouse events like follows.

```
def mousePressEvent(self,event):
    self.startx=event.x()
    self.starty=event.y()
def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event):
    self.endx=event.x()
    self.endy=event.y()
    newLine = line(QtCore.QPoint(self.startx, self.starty), QtCore.QPoint(self.endx, self.endy))
```

This should allow the user to click and drag the mouse and then upon releasing the mouse it should draw the line and not effect whatever else is drawn.  I usually do things in QGraphicsScenes and it is a little bit different, but the concept should be about the same for this.  If you want to have the line being drawn as the user drags the mouse I know how to do that also, but the way I know is much more complicated than this and I would recommend using a QGraphicsScene to handle that, just message me if you want me to explain how I have done it.

Comment: Thank you very much Brock . But the control goes to the constructor in line object , but the paintEvent() doesn't get called ( i added print statements ) .Also , i would be pleased if u give me how to do this via QraphicsScene .( I can't get ur mail-id. ) Thanx again.

Comment: Alright lets see how well I can explain this....A QGraphicsScene is like a container that holds many objects(QGraphicsItems) inside of it.  A QGraphicsView is what you place in the GUI that paints the contents of the scene on the screen.  You can draw and interact with anything you want in a QGraphicsScene, you can even use OpenGL acceleration if you want.  Anyways, enough with the endorsement, here is a link that will get you started as far as making your QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene and linking your scene to your view: [http://lateral.netmanagers.com.ar/stories/BBS53.html]

Comment: That tutorial I just linked does a good job of explaining everything and it is how I first started to understand how QGraphicsScenes worked.  The only problem is it is not written in PyQt4 and I could not get the code to work with my version of pyqt I used so I will write up some code to show you the process of drawing a line in a QGraphicsScene and this tutorial should educate you a little so when I get the code ready it should be easy to understand and see how it works.

Comment: Really a good tutorial . I'm working in modifying my code now . Thank you very much for your kind support...:)

Comment: Alright so here is the sample code I promised: http://www.megaupload.com/?d=696T2A11. There are lots of comments in it so you should be able to understand how it is working.  I just quickly threw this code together so there is a few bugs such as when the user clicks and releases without moving the mouse, but for the main part it works fine.  If you have any questions about it you can find me on twitter: BrockS_18, that is probably the most sure way (I don't really want to just publicly post my e-mail), or you can just post again on here and hopefully I will see it.  Anyways, I hope it helps.

Comment: Wow , i've inducted the code into my app and it worked so good . Nice and wonderful program that. Now i'm implementing other image manipulation functions as well...Thank u so much ...